# Why function onClick run by render, in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.setState({
  Products:  products.map((product, index) => {
    return(
      <div className="catalog-item" onClick="console.log('click)" key={index} data-id={product._id}>
        <div className="catalog-item__top">
          <h4>{product.name}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  })
})
```

The function onClick run when rendering, but i need run only Click to element
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to events in react. You can't pass just function name as string like in html

```
<div className="catalog-item" onClick={() => console.log('click')} key={index} data-id={product._id}>
```